# Memcached error: address already in use

Tags: memcached

When I run:

```
memcached -u nobody -l 0.0.0.0:11211,0.0.0.0:11212
```

it gives me the error:

> Failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more substancial, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also reformatted your question so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Last, I would recommend you to edit the question and include more information as for example how is memcached configured and what you're trying to achieve. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using 127.0.0.1 instead of using 0.0.0.0 as the IP address for accessing memcache

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
memcached -u nobody -l 0.0.0.0:11211 && memcached -u nobody -l 0.0.0.0:11212
```